# How to iterate over this embedded JSON "list" in python?

Tags: python, json

New to python here. I'm trying to iterate over all the JSON "group" objects for each person but having some difficulty. This is only a partial list (not all users have groups) so I need to use the try/catch block so users without a list of groups don't cause early termination.

The JSON data snippet:

```
{
"people": [
   {

      "person": {
         "name": "joe",
         "email": "joe@foo.net",

         "groups": [
            {
               "name": "office",
               "id": 23
            },

            {
               "name": "mfg",
               "id": 93
            } ]
      },


      "person": {
         "name": "bill",
         "email": "bill@foo.net",

         "groups": [
            {
               "name": "acctg",
               "id": 133
            },

            {
               "name": "mgr",
               "id": 207
            } ]
      } 
   }
]

}
```

This is my code so far:

```
jdata = json.loads...
for person in jdata['people']:
   for key, val in person.iteritems():
      print "key ", key , " is ", val

      print val["name"]
      print val["email"]

      try:
         for gkey, gval in val["groups"][0].iteritems():
            print "gval: " + gval
      except:
         foo=1
```

Notice I can print out a list of the 0th item in the group list by doing the `for gkey...val["groups"][0].iteritems()` but what I really want is iterate over all the `group` lists of each `person` entry (some people belong to two groups, others 10 or more) so there is no fixed length. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a `for` loop on `val["groups"]`. Or is that not what you want?

Comment: Instead of try/except, you can say val.get("groups", []) and the iterate over that. If that person doesn't have groups it will return an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want? :

```
>>> for group in j['people'][0]['person']['groups']:
        for k,v in group.items():
            print(k,v)


name acctg
id 133
name mgr
id 207
```

Or more generally:

```
>>> for person in j['people']:
        for group in person['person']['groups']:
            print('Name : {} --- ID: {}'.format(group['name'], group['id']))


Name : acctg --- ID: 133
Name : mgr --- ID: 207
```

Comment: Thanks! The second example you show is just what I needed. whew!